# Getting an Unhandled Promise Rejection when attempting to play Youtube video using discord.js

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

So I've been working on a discord bot for my friend's server. I've never had a formal education in coding, so I just kind of throw stuff together until it works. After adding the ability to play a youtube video through the bot, I'm getting an unhandled promise rejection from time to time when trying to play audio from the bot. What confuses me is not why the promise rejection happens (it happens because the connection times out after 15 seconds), but why it only happens *sometimes*. Here's the code in question:

```js
const link = args[0];
if (validUrl.isUri(link)) {
  console.log(">Link Is Valid");
  if (
    link.includes("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=") ||
    link.includes("https://youtu.be/")
  ) {
    console.log(">Link Is A youtube.com Link");
    if (link.includes("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=")) {
      const vidId = link.slice(32);
      if (!vidId.length === 11) {
        console.log(">Invalid YT Video ID; Returned");
        message.channel.send("Invalid YT Video ID");
        return;
      }
      if (playing === true) {
        console.log(">A YT Video Is Already Playing; Returned");
        message.channel.send("A YT Video Is Already Playing");
        return;
      } else {
        const connection = await message.member.voice.channel.join();
        const dispatcher = connection.play(await ytdl(link), {
          type: "opus",
          bitrate: 192000,
          volume: 0.7,
        });
        dispatcher.on("start", () => {
          playing = true;
          console.log(">Linked Video Is Playing");
        });
        dispatcher.on("finish", () => {
          playing = false;
          console.log(">Linked Video Has Finished Playing");
          connection.disconnect();
        });
        return;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The exact error I get is this:

> (node:12412) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [VOICE_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT]: Connection not established within 15 seconds.

Sometimes it works just fine, outputting

```
>Link Is Valid
>Link Is A youtube.com Link
>Linked Video Is Playing
```

Does anyone have any idea how to either handle the promise exception or eliminate the issue altogether?

Comment: 1) You should add the error to your question and not in a comment. 2) you are using `await ...` in an async function, but I don't see any `try ... catch`. So if the promise you are awaiting rejects, you don't catch that, hence the warning. 3) as for the timeout itself that can have many reasons, not necessarily coming from your code.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. Sorry if I get any terminology wrong, like I said I've never been formally taught to code. I'll try adding `try ... catch` to those statements and see how it goes with the members on the server.